# `EventMapOf<T extends EventTarget>` that returns the “EventMap” used by T

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

In `lib.dom.d.ts` we have

```
interface EventTarget {
    addEventListener(type: string, callback: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject | null, options?: AddEventListenerOptions | boolean): void;
    dispatchEvent(event: Event): boolean;
    removeEventListener(type: string, callback: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject | null, options?: EventListenerOptions | boolean): void;
}
```

and various types that implement this have functions of the form

```
interface FooEventMap {
  "foo": FooEvent;
}

interface Foo extends EventTarget {
    addEventListener<K extends keyof FooEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Foo, ev: FooEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener<K extends keyof FooEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Foo, ev: FooEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | EventListenerOptions): void;
}
```

And I would like to write some type `EventMapOf<T extends EventTarget>` such that `EventMapOf<Foo>` is the type `FooEventMap`. I specifically want to extract it from the type itself as declared in `lib.dom.d.ts`, that is, by analyzing the signatures of `addEventListener` and/or `removeEventListener` for any given `T`, including types that are not found in `lib.dom.d.ts`.

This means one cannot hard-code a list of event maps and consult that. I already have a solution of this form, but it’s very awkward for my purposes (which includes several custom event targets and I do not want to have to maintain a “master list” of all types of this format).

(I am also aware that `dispatchEvent` can be used to dispatch events that are not found in a given type’s event map, even for native types, and I have a solution for that, but that’s beyond the scope of this question. For the sake of this question, assume that the `FooEventMap` is the full-and-complete list of events allowed for `Foo`.)

I’ve made several attempts at this, but so far have had no luck:

- The base `EventTarget` overload is a serious problem, as it makes it impossible (so far as I can tell) to extract the string literals in use (they all get conflated under `string`). Using `Exclude` to try to remove that overload just results in `never`. It’s also apparently impossible to separate the overloads—they aren’t considered to be a union and don’t distribute the way type unions do. As far as I can tell, you can’t get the `FooEventMap[K]` type even if you hard-code in the `K` as some `keyof FooEventMap`, it’s still just `Event`. You can’t use `Foo['addEventListener']<K>` at all, it will error on the `<`.
- Trying to infer the generic constraint itself doesn’t work:

  ```
  interface TypedEventAdder<EventMap> {
    addEventListener<K extends keyof EventMap>(
      type: K,
      listener: (ev: EventMap[K]) => any,
      options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions,
    ): void;
  }

  export type EventMapOf<Target extends EventTarget> =
    Target extends TypedEventAdder<infer EventMap> ? EventMap : never;
  ```

  The result here is always `unknown` (or equal to whatever constraint I put on `EventMap` in `TypedEventAdder`). Adding the `string` overload to `TypedEventAdder` doesn’t help, either.

Answer (score -1):

You need to expose the `FooEventMap`interface globally like so

```
declare global {
  interface FooEventMap {
    "foo": FooEvent;
  }
}
```

This way a consumer of your event target will be able to extends the FooEventMap and customize it the same way.

Comment: It doesn’t, because that’s literally the thing the question is trying to avoid doing. The whole point of the question is to extract that information from the existing library _without_ rewriting it (or editing `lib.dom.d.ts`).