# Determine specific types of overloads when last overload is generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Consider a function like this:

```ts
declare function foo(arg: 1): 'foo';
declare function foo(arg: 2): 'foofoo';
declare function foo(arg: number): string;
```

Is there any way for a generic type to determine that `1` and `2` are special, overloaded inputs? Is there any way to determine `'foo'` and `'foofoo'` as special return values? Most especially, is there any way to extract the relationship between them, so we have some notion that `1 → 'foo'` and `2 → 'foofoo'`? That will work on any overloaded `(arg: string) => number` function?

Does anything change if we define `foo` like this?

```ts
type M = { 1: 'foo'; 2: 'foofoo' };
declare function foo<A extends keyof M>(arg: A): M[A];
declare function foo(arg: string): number;
```

(Assuming we can’t just hard-code `M` here, and only have `typeof foo` to work with.)

As far as I can tell, `number` and `string` “shadow” all of the specific values and no amount of jumping through hoops will get Typescript to extract, infer, or otherwise manipulate the more specific types in the type domain.¹ I’m hoping I’m wrong and I’ve missed something.

My motivation (and attempts) are [my previous question about `…EventMap` types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77131649/778430), but I thought this much-simpler question would possibly receive more attention.

1. <sub>Obviously just *calling* `foo(2)` will be typed correctly as `'foofoo'`, but without hard-coding the `2` there’s no way to get that and anyway there’s no way to “call” `foo` in the type domain.</sub>

Comment: You can't infer from overloads like this.  But you don't need an overload for this sort of thing, just a single call signature acting on a type with an index signature like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdOQYw) shows.  But either way, starting with a function type and trying to infer `M` from it is not going to work because TS doesn't have higher order generics.  This whole thing looks backwards: why can't you start with `M` and define the function from it?  Or at least *check* the function from it?  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz Higher-order types would certainly be useful here, but I’m not certain they are necessary. For example, _without_ overloads, we can recreate `M` from `typeof foo` without issue by jumping through some hoops and using conditional type distribution, a union-to-intersection type, etc. ([Playground example](https://tsplay.dev/w6VlGw)) Overloads are still an issue—can’t use `typeof foo<K>` when `foo` isn’t generic and just has overloads—but the lack of higher-order types can be worked around in at least some cases. The way `number` and `string` “shadow” everything, though...

Comment: @jcalz As for being “backwards,” yes, see the other question for the motivation: the various “`foo`” functions I want to analyze, and their respective “`M`s,” come from `lib.dom.d.ts` and there are about 220 of them—and more could be added in updates or by the user.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't call that "without issue" (you're using instantiation expression meaning you're not just using `typeof foo`, you're using `typeof (foo<K>)`, which is different.  This is close to using higher order generics, but you need a concrete `foo` to work with, not just its type) but I see what you mean.  Anyway I expect the answer here to be "you can't do this" from overloads, and if workarounds moving away from overloads don't help, then I guess I don't have much insight apart from that.  Maybe someone will post a clever answer here.

Comment: @jcalz Oh, hm, yeah, you’re right. I was just doing that as a way to do it quick and with less fluff, but there’s no way to take it as a generic and manipulate it from there. Ouch, then you’re probably right, without higher-order types there is just no way it’s going to happen. Very frustrating.